# show that$v(E) = a_1a_2a_3....a_nv(B^n)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, determinant

I'm generally pretty good a change in variable type problems, but this one has me stumped. It's on page 264 in Advanced calculus of several variables by Edwards.

Thm 5.1: If $\lambda:R^n \rightarrow R^n$ is a linear mapping and $B \subset R^n$ is contented, then $\lambda(B)$ is also contented, and $v(\lambda(B)) = |det\lambda|v(B)$

Here is the question:

Consider the n-dimensional solid ellipsoid $$E =  \{x \in R^n: \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i^2}{a_i^2}\}$$

note that $E$ is the image of the unit ball $B^n$ under the mapping $ T: R^n \rightarrow R^n$ defined by $$T(x_1,....,x_n) = (a_1x_1,.....,a_nx_n)$$

apply thm 5.1 to show that $v(E) = a_1a_2a_3....a_nv(B^n)$

thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that  $|\det T|=a_1a_2\cdots a_n$.  You can do this by imposing an orthonormal basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and taking the determinant of that matrix.  The standard basis will do, and $T$ sends it to the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, which has determinant $a_1a_2\cdots a_n$, as desired.

Comment: so i multiply the orthonormal basis of R * T = the diagonal matrix desired ?

Comment: $T$ is not a matrix, $T$ is a linear map.  It sends $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ to $(a_1,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$.  It sends $(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ to $(0,a_2,0,\ldots,0)$, etc.  If you haven't had a linear algebra course, you can read the basics [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: yea i just realized that... god im slow. thanks for your patience, i should think more before i type. again thanks.

Comment: @Neo, my pleasure